# ios - how do I properly set up my provisioning and code signing for AdHoc builds for testing on a device?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios6, ad-hoc-distribution

I have added a development provisioning profile called "Alex provisioning" and added my device to it.

Then I added a distribution provisioning profile named "Ad hoc profile" just because I meant to use it for testing. Then I added my device to it.

Then for the code signing, I used both of these.

And then I archived and saved the .ipa file using the "save as AdHoc build" feature.

But then when I put the app on the device, I got this error:

```
Mar 31 12:04:30 ancient-phone lsd[12249] <Warning>: Attempting to store identifiers file
Mar 31 12:04:30 ancient-phone installd[12247] <Error>: 0x2ffac000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.44s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 1.26s; LS Sync: 0.05s; Overall: 1.95s
Mar 31 12:04:31 ancient-phone installd[12247] <Error>: 0x2ffac000 filter_attributes: Info.plist keys requested via MobileInstallationLookup/Browse in client Xcode (via mobile_installation_proxy) were not found in MobileInstallation's cache. Please file a bug requesting that these keys be added: <CFBasicHash 0x1e6368c0 [0x39b4f100]>{type = mutable set, count = 18,
    entries =>
        0 : <CFString 0x39b3b9f4 [0x39b4f100]>{contents = "CFBundlePackageType"}
        1 : <CFString 0x1e6275d0 [0x39b4f100]>{contents = "BuildMachineOSBuild"}
        2 : <CFString 0x39b3ca44 [0x39b4f100]>{contents = "CFBundleResourceSpecification"}
        3 : <CFString 0x1e630980 [0x39b4f100]>{contents = "DTPlatformBuild"}
        4 : <CFString 0x39b39794 [0x39b4f100]>{contents = "DTCompiler"}
        5 : <CFString 0x39b3b564 [0x39b4f100]>{contents = "CFBundleSignature"}
        6 : <CFString 0x39b3c224 [0x39b4f100]>{contents = "DTSDKName"}
        7 : <CFString 0x1e53f9c0 [0x39b4f100]>{contents = "NSBundleResolvedPath"}
        8 : <CFString 0x39b38eb4 [0x39b4f100]>{contents = "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"}
        10 : <CFString 0x39b40e84 [0x39b4f100]>{contents = "DTXcode"}
        13 : <CFString 0x39b40eb4 [0x39b4f100]>{contents = "CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion"}
        16 : <CFString 0x39b3e304 [0x39b4f100]>{contents = "CFBundleSupportedPlatforms"}
        17 : <CFString 0x1e549610 [0x39b4f100]>{contents = "DTXcodeBuild"}
        18 : <CFString 0x1e62bdd0 [0x39b4f100]>{contents = "UIStatusBarTintParameters"}
        19 : <CFString 0x39b3ce54 [0x39b4f100]>{contents = "DTPlatformVersion"}
        20 : <CFString 0x39b3fbf4 [0x39b4f100]>{contents = "DTPlatformName"}
        21 : <CFString 0x39b40c84 [0x39b4f100]>{contents = "CFBundleDevelopmentRegion"}
        22 : <CFString 0x1e62bac0 [0x39b4f100]>{contents = "DTSDKBuild"}
    }
```

I am suspecting I probably misunderstood something about all the provisioning files I had to make and all the code signing.

Does something in the process I described sound not right? Should I have just added the device to my original provisioning profiles?